# thare are sales from google ads campiagn but no recent conversions in google ads

Tags: google-ads

I connected google ads event (purchase) in my store with GTM, and make sure the event is correctly set in GTM & in Google Ads
but, there are some sales came from google ad campaign without any number in google ads as in the picture below, what is the reason of this problem ?[image]